# R - grab first portion of file name

Tags: regex, r, file

I have lots of files in a directory `dir`, with the following format

```
[xyz][sequence of numbers or letters]_[single number]_[more stuff that does not matter].csv
```

for example, `xyz39289_3_8932jda.csv`

I would like to write a function that returns all the first portions of all the file names in that directory. By first portion, I mean the `[xyz][sequence of numbers]` portion. So, in the example above, this would include the `xyz39289`. As such, the function would ultimately return a list such as

```
[xyz39289, xyz9382, xyz03319927, etc]
```

How can I do this in R? In Java, I would do the following:

```
File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles();
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   output.add(files[i].getName().substring(0,files[i].getName().indexOf("_"));
}
```

Comment: `^xyz[^_]+` or `^xyz[0-9]+` or just split at the underscore and use the first element in the split array

Comment: What? I don't know what to do with those regex expressions...

Comment: It's unclear whether "xyz" is meant to be exactly those letters or to be any alpha character. A better list of examples would assist responders in constructing a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get your list of files with `list.files` (and possibly extract just the files that you want that begin with `xyz`, I'd use `sub`.

```
files <- list.files(dir)
files <- files[grep("^xyz",files, perl = TRUE)]
filepart <- sub("^(xyz[^_]*)_.*$","\\1",files, perl = TRUE)
```

There's also a `regexpr` method that I'm not too certain with. Something like

```
files <- list.files(dir)
matchdat <- regexpr("^xyz.*?(?=_)",files, perl = TRUE)
filepart <- regmatches(test,matchdat)
```

Comment: I'm using your first method. The filepart seems to return the same thing as the files array. It doesn't seem to be cutting off everything from the names

Comment: I added a `$` to the regex. Try it now.

Comment: same thing still, unfortunately

Comment: Can you show me an element in `files` where it doesn't work? This appears to work: `sub("^(xyz\\d+)_.*$","\\1","xyz39289_3_8932jda.csv")`

Comment: > sub("^(xyz\\d+)_.*$","\\1","xyzfe55dc59_2_2013-10-16 09-30-09.csv", perl = TRUE)
[1] "xyzfe55dc59_2_2013-10-16 09-30-09.csv" - sorry, there are actually numbers and letters after the xyz and before the underscore

Comment: Ah, okay. I was using `\\d` to match the digits. Now that you say otherwise, I replaced that with `[^_]`, any character that isn't an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Might be easiest to delete everything after the first `_`.

```
sub("_.*$", "", files)
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful when combined with the answer I chose below

Answer (score 0):

here's another version. list all files

```
myfiles <- list.files(path="./dir")
```

split each file name on "_" and keep the first part

```
myfiles.pre <- sapply(myfiles, function(x) strsplit(x,"_",fixed=T)[[1]][1])
```