# Retrieve portion of file name

Tags: regex, r, file, filenames

I have a number of files with the following format:

```
sub_(number 1 to 60)_ sess_(number 1, 2, or 3)_ (some letters)_ DDMMMYYYY_(some number with either 3 or 4 digit).txt
```

For example:

```
sub_41_sess_2_ABCxyz_23Feb2016_2932.txt
```

I want to retrieve only the portion '(1, 2, or 3)' after the 'sess_' portion and I think `sub()` function can return all those numbers. I refer to these URLs, [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719400/r-grab-first-portion-of-file-name?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Here's the code I tried, didn't work:

```
dir <- "path/"
filelist = list.files(path = dir, pattern = ".*.txt")
filelist

for (f in filelist) {

    sess_id <- sub("^(sub_[1-60])^(_sess_)(1 |2 |3)^.*","\\1",c(f), perl = TRUE)

}
sess_id
```

What was returned was a single filename that looks like this:

```
[1] "subject_9_4Feb2016_1611.txt"
```

I am expecting something like below, because I need each `sess_id` to be an attribute of the files with overall file format stated above.

```
[1] "1" or [1] "2"
```

Comment: you can try `sub("sub_\\d+_sess_(\\d{1})_.*", "\\1", "sub_41_sess_2_ABCxyz_23Feb2016_2932.txt")` `[1] "2"`

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the string `"sub_41_sess_2_ABCxyz_23Feb2016_2932.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using `gsub` by matching all the characters until the `sess` followed by `_` or `|` the characters that start with `_` followed by upper case letters followed by characters (`.*`) until the end of the string (`$`), and replace with `''`.

```
gsub('^.*sess\\_|\\_[A-Z]+.*$', '', str1)
#[1] "2"
```

---

Or using `str_extract`, it would be much more compact.  By default, `str_extract` only extract the first occurrence of the match.  Here we extract the numbers (`\\d+`) that follow the regex lookaround (`(?<=sess_)`).

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, '(?<=sess_)\\d+')
#[1] "2"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "sub_41_sess_2_ABCxyz_23Feb2016_2932.txt")
```

Comment: If i use the 'for' function as shown in the question, will the str_extract() function loop through all the files that i have in the directory? I tried your 2nd method with the 'for' loop and only the last file in list.files was processed.

Comment: @user94216 Yes, you can use `for` loop, but have to create an output object as `list`.  Or else use `lapply` to loop through the files and apply `str_extract`.  i.e. `sapply(files, function(x) str_extract(x, '(?<=sess_)\\d+'))`

Answer (score 1):

It means that you need everything after the third "_". If that is so
load the `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
a<-"sub_41_sess_2_ABCxyz_23Feb2016_2932.txt"
str_sub(a, start=str_locate_all(a, "_")[[1]][3]+1, end = str_locate_all(a, "_")[[1]][3]+1 )

[1] "2"
```